# 2 Ajax requests are being made from 1 call, 1 is failing the other is CORS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 5 WEB API enabled site, which is using CORS to allow communication between the two. My problem is that when I go to delete through the API, I make one ajax call, but two requests are made. As you can see below, one is a regular request, and the other is a CORS compliant request, and the CORS request is obviously making it through, and it's deleting the item. However what I don't understand is why the other one is even there. Any ideas? I've already checked to see if multiple event handlers are on the element and any sort of problem related to that. So it's definitely only being called once.

**REQUEST 1(CORS) - The one I'm actually calling**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 17:18:09 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**REQUEST 2(???)**

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 29 Jul 2015 17:18:09 GMT
Content-Length: 8167
```

**Delete AJAX function**

```
function deleteItem() {
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.parentNode)
    killParent = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    targetID = event.target.id
    confirmDel = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete site #" + targetID + "?");
    if (confirmDel == true) {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'DELETE',
             url: 'http://intranet/APITest/api/sites/' + targetID + '/',
             crossDomain: true,
             success: function() {
                 $("#row" + targetID).remove();
             },
             error: function (error) {
                 alert(error);
             }
         }); 
    } else if(confirmDel == false){
        alert("Site #" + targetID + " was not deleted.")
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: is there a redirection operation in the ajax target page?

Comment: None, it isn't even refreshing, I'm just removing the row after it succeeds. The API doesn't redirect either.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using DELETE, the first one is likely a [pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS)

If you check in the browser tools what HTTP method it actually uses for the first one, you're likely to see something like `OPTIONS http://intranet/APITest/api/sites/123` in the request.

Browsers usually make one of these when you initiate a cross-domain AJAX request, especially when using a non-standard method such as DELETE.

From the MDN documentation (in the link above):

> In CORS, a preflight request with the OPTIONS method is sent, so that
>   the server can respond whether it is acceptable to send the request
>   with these parameters. The Access-Control-Request-Method header
>   notifies the server as part of a preflight request that when the
>   actual request is sent, it will be sent with a POST request method.
>   The Access-Control-Request-Headers header notifies the server that
>   when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a X-PINGOTHER
>   and Content-Type custom headers.  The server now has an opportunity to
>   determine whether it wishes to accept a request under these
>   circumstances.